# Not able to automatically open soft keyboard on app startup

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am a begginer on Java and Android dev.

As you launch Google Search, the Soft Keyboard immediatly appears.

I'm trying to do the same. I searched a lot and i see that there are many different ways to obtain this, the problem is that none of them seems to work

**requestFocus()**

in my Activity i tried to

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
      searchEditText.requestFocus();
    });
```

**requestFocus (xml)**

in my xml layout file i tried to

```
    <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
      android:hint="@string/search"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:imeOptions="actionSend"
      android:singleLine="true">
      <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

**manifest**

in the manifest xml I tried

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

and

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

**InputMethodManager**

in the Activity I tried

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    });
```

**Runnable**

in my Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

    searchEditText.requestFocus();
    searchEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(searchEditText, 0);
        }
    },200);;
});
```

As I said in the begging, I'm sure it could work, cause it works on Google Search.

Comment: Is this on a device or in the simulator. I get issues in the simulator when the Keyboard setting is not checked in my
 settings

Comment: It happens on real device: HTC Desire Z

Answer (score 1):

have you tried playing with manifest for this?

try the below code hope it helps

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

for more information regarding this [Read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: It works, but with strange behavior: if I "exit" the app with the "home button", the keyboards remains open and if I "re-open" the app, the keyboard won't appear again. But if I "exit" the app with the "back button" it works as expected. I also can't undestand why it works with "adjustPan" and it doesn't with "adjustResize" that are nearly the same thing!

Comment: i would give that a try,but that would be a different question,i didn't needed to use this,but still i'll try

Comment: As i said in my question, I would like to obtain a behavior like Google Search, in this app, every time you "open" the app, the keyboard shows up

Comment: @nulll : it appears on startup because we are forcing it to in the activity startup by using the above code